# Windows 7 Enterprise with no Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

For some reason when I installed Windows 7 Enterprise, it didn't install Windows Media Player. There doesn't seem to be any way to download WMP because everything says it installs by default in Windows 7.

[This site](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/01/12/how-to-uninstall-and-re-install-windows-media-player-12-wmp12-in-windows-7/) describes how to uninstall and re-install it but I don't even have the *Media Features* option in *Turn Windows features on or off* section in Control Panel.

Anybody know a way to install it? About the only thing I can think of doing is trying an "upgrade" of my original installation but that's kind of a last resort measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have Windows 7N. The 'N' means 'Not with Media Player'. See this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions) for details

Please see [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=31017ed3-166a-4c75-b90c-a6cef9b414c4&displayLang=en) for the Media Feature Pack download for Windows 7N & Windows 7KN.